# AutoCompleteTextview data from mysql jdbc

Tags: android

Please help me to implement AutoCompleteTextView :

I am getting date from mysql server using bellow's AsynTask code. now i want to implement a AutoCompleteTextView using those date also when i will select a emp_name from the list then emp_id will show in a textview separately.

i am new in android so pls make the ans: like a project.
**Advance Thanks**

```
##
        private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

      protected void onPreExecute()
       { 
        }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

         try 
        {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + IP + ":3306/hrms","root", "xdcf33df");
            String empid=null;
            String empcode=null;
            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) st.executeQuery("select id,employee_name from emp");
            while(rs.next()) {
                empid=rs.getString(1);
                empcode=rs.getString(2);

        }
            st.close();
            con.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {

        }
    }
##
```